# Linear fit with gnuplot producing incorrect results?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I am trying to use GNUplot to calculate the best-fit line for some time-series data. The data is just about linear already with a negative slope. The input data looks something like:

```
1615840396,138849,510249
1615840406,139011,511152
1615840416,137580,510330
1615840426,137493,510501
1615840436,137261,510186
1615840447,137435,511026
1615840456,137054,510252
1615840466,136955,510174
1615840476,136922,510540
1615840486,136970,510999
```

The first column is a Unix timestamp. A graph of column 2 vs. time looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to produce a best-fit line like this:

```
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt "%s"
gnuplot> set datafile separator comma
gnuplot> f(x) = m*x + b
gnuplot> fit f(x) 'data.csv' using 1:2 via m,b
```

Which produces:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
m               = 8.08062e-05      +/- 1.633        (2.021e+06%)
b               = 1                +/- 2.639e+09    (2.639e+11%)
```

The resulting best fit line has a positive slope, and doesn't really git the data at all:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the answer solve your problem? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: does the answer solve your problem? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurring question about fitting time data. I guess there should be similar questions here on SO, but I can't find them right now. I'm not sure if there is an example of fitting time data on the gnuplot homepage.

I guess the problem is the following: If you assume a linear function `f(x) = a*x + b` with time data, the origin will be at Jan, 1st 1970.
Typically, this will be pretty far from your actual data and furthermore, you only have a small range of data compared to the distance to your origin. So, I guess the fitting function cannot deliver really good values.

You better try to fit a function which is shifted by your start date.
You either set this start date manually, or you spend a few lines of code to find it automatically.
Additionally, it will help if you give some starting values for the fitting parameters.
Here, it seems that `a` will be found without giving a start value and if you set `b=1` it will not give good result, but `b=10` seems to be ok as starting value.

**Code:**

```
### fitting time data
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
do for [i=1:100] { 
  print sprintf("%.0f,%g",time(0)+i*86400,i+rand(0)*10 ) 
  }
set print

set datafile separator comma

# find out the StartDate
StartDate = 16158768671          # manually by setting a value
# or automatically by using stats
stats $Data u 1 index 0 every ::0:0:0:0 nooutput
StartDate = STATS_min

f(x) = a*(x-StartDate) + b
set fit brief nolog
b=10
fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via a,b
set key top left
set format x "%b %d" timedate

plot $Data u 1:2 ti "Data", \
     f(x) w l lc rgb "red" ti "Fit"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 1.16005e-05      +/- 1.163e-07    (1.003%)
b               = 6.1323           +/- 0.5759       (9.39%)
```

[image]

Comment: Or `stats 'data.csv' nooutput` and `StartDate = STATS_min_x` before setting time options.

Comment: @maij yes, right, that's another way and probably clearer code and maybe even faster. But be aware, in case the time format is not unix timestamp you have to convert the time format back and forth using `strptime()` and `strftime()`.