Gnuplot fit vs excel trendline
I try to do linear regression on datapoints and was wondering why gnuplot fit is different to an excel trendline and my powershellscript.
My datapoints:
Timestamp   Value
1709289398  3.89
1711018216  3.9
1711450016  3.93
1711460288  3.91
1711462458  3.92
1711618830  3.95
1711620395  3.94
1711630819  3.95
1711635811  3.93
1711638487  3.91
1712057838  3.96
1712578056  3.93
1712590907  3.89
1712662297  3.95
1712918775  3.9
1712924128  3.94
1713170534  3.98
1713191398  3.94
1713773713  3.94
1713776247  3.97
1713777374  3.96
1713790153  3.97
1713860582  3.96
1713881074  3.86
1713882272  3.89
1714032046  3.94
1714033372  3.86
1714045066  3.8
1714055405  3.81
1714382965  3.82
1714478636  3.78
1714494189  3.96
1714496044  3.95
1714496681  3.95
1714652333  3.97
1714654135  4.01
1714732802  4.02
1714735452  4.01
1714736266  4.07
1714737131  3.99
1714748973  4.02
1714984178  4.24
1715006630  4
1715181736  3.91
1715599718  3.88
1715675239  3.87
1717430326  3.91
1717432138  3.88
1717750408  3.98

This is my powershell funtion that gives me nearly the same output as a trendline in excel:
function Find-LinearRegession($dataPoints) {
    $n = $dataPoints.Length
    $sumX = 0
    $sumY = 0
    $sumXY = 0
    $sumXX = 0

    foreach ($point in $dataPoints) {
        $x = $point[0]
        $y = $point[1]

        $sumX += $x
        $sumY += $y
        $sumXY += $x * $y
        $sumXX += $x * $x
    }

    $meanX = $sumX / $n
    $meanY = $sumY / $n

    $slope = (($n * $sumXY) - ($sumX * $sumY)) / (($n * $sumXX) - ($sumX * $sumX))
    $intercept = $meanY - ($slope * $meanX)

    return @{
        Slope     = $slope
        Intercept = $intercept
    }
}

Excel: y = 0,000000005343803x - 5,221042665245090
Powershell: y = 0,000000005343795x - 5,2210293420428
Now i saw that gnuplot got a fit function and i was thinking if both (trendline and fit) doing the same.
But after a view trys i cant figure it out. Here is my Gnuplotscript
data = 'GnuPlotValues.txt'
set ticslevel 0
set tics nomirror
set key noautotitle
set grid
set key font ',14'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%d/%m/%y"
set xtics rotate by 45 right
a = 1
b = 1
g(x) = a*x + b
fit g(x) data using 1:2 via a, b
f(x) = 5.34379555506111E-09*x + -5.2210293420428    
plot data using 1:2 with points pt 7 ps 0.6 lc rgb 'red' title 'Datapoints', \
    g(x) with lines, \
    f(x) with lines title 'Linear regression: f(x) = 5.3437E-09x + -5.221'

The Output looks like this:

Red is the Gnuplot fit and blue is the powershellscript function. Now iam wondering what is correct and what is the better choice for a linear regression. Can someone tell me why both have such a differance in slope?

What happens to your powershell calculations if you sort the inputs before processing them?

@WalterMitty They sorted by the timestamp.
now i sorted them by the value.
Slope = 5,34379555670356E-09
Intercept = -5,2210293448575

You are trying to fit time data. I guess Excel is using days passed from 1900-01-01 and gnuplot is using seconds passed from 1970-01-01. I guess your problem with gnuplot is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650594/7295599

"trendline" is not a technical term - it can refer to any of several different fitting algorithms.  In gnuplot you must provide an explicit function and weighting scheme; this may or may not match whatever it is that Excel does by default.

I have a linear regression script that I wrote as a learning exercise.  I plugged your data in and got results almost identical to yours.  The difference might be due to the fact that I used double precision.  I'm not providing it as an answer because it doesn't address your real question, which is about Gnuplot.

I did a little research and I found out that Gnuplot uses an unusual algorithm for curve fitting.  The algorithm is adapted to non linear functions.  But that's irrelevevant, and perhaps harmful, in your case.  Here is the description of the algorithm.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm

This is a real stretch.  I know nothing about Gnuplot, and can't try it out here.
But I offer it on the off chance that it might shed some light on the difference between Gnuplot and Excel.
Go through your data and subtract 1709289398 from each of the timestamps to produce a new dataset.  The value I typed in is the value of your first timestamp.  In the new dataset, this first entry will be zero.
Do the excel test with this new dataset,  and also do the Gnuplot. If my guess is correct,  the slope on the Excel will be unchanged, but the slope in the Gnuplot will be nearly the same as the excel result.
Finally, run the new dataset through your powershell function.  The slope and intercept should still be the same as the excel.
I'm basing this response based on some of the comments that talked about time series data, and some anomalies that come up with timestamps.  If this is a waste of your time, I apologize.

I tried it that way, but unfortunately the slopes still do not match. I have now found another approach. Even with quadratic fits, gnuplot does not behave as expected.

If you still have an interest, I took some time to both study your results, provide some background information that details the apparent differences you are observing, and propose a slight change to your input data that significantly enhances search algorithm convergence to the global optimum. The attached note provides the details, and the attached compressed file contains a directory with an example script I refer to in the note. I hope this is helpful!
Let me know if you have any trouble accessing either of the following URL.
Shawn
Document:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnM-GsAEZPoSsj0FbogBsUV6jgux?e=aC8zp5
Compressed file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnM-GsAEZPoSsj7WoVCl-FPIdGfM?e=3YVtaK
